# How to reliably transfer files to the Android Emulator SDCard with a GUI?

Tags: android, file, emulation, transfer

Using commandline is really tedious (welcome to the 80s!) so I would like to know if there is a tool to transfer files to the Android Emulator SDCard with a GUI.

I already tried qtadb but that thing fails all the time on androidx86 in a virtual machine and doesn't work at all with the emulator.

Is there something reliable or a way to mount the sdcard from the emulator so I can access it with the windows explorer or a comparable tool with a decent GUI ?

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to know if there is a tool to transfer files to the Android Emulator SDCard with a GUI.

Use DDMS. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html):

> DDMS provides a File Explorer tab that allows you to view, copy, and delete files on the device. This feature is useful in examining files that are created by your application or if you want to transfer files to and from the device.
>
> To work with an emulator or device's file system:
>
> 1. In the Devices tab, select the emulator that you want to view the file system for.
> 2. To copy a file from the device, locate the file in the File Explorer and click the Pull file button.
> 3. To copy a file to the device, click the Push file button on the File Explorer tab.

(note that in standalone DDMS, the "File Explorer tab" is really a separate window launched from the main menu)

Comment: Thanks for the advice but unfortunately the file transfer in DDMS is rather badly designed. It cannot remove directories and bulk transfer is also not that well implemented and working with it is generally rather tedious. But its a start...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Windows operating system, XP, VISTA, or Windows 7, you can use WinImage. You can find it at: http://www.winimage.com/order.htm. I created a 32 gig SD card image on the Samsung Galaxy Note emulator that we created and I used WinImage to copy 6 gigs of map files so that I could develop and test our offline mapping application. I was able to view all the files on the SD card from the Gallery application on the emulated device. It comes with a 30 day evaluation period and costs $30US to purchase, but if you do this frequently in your development, it's worth it.